# Is there a way to open a website link, and using the console, run custom code on the opened website using JS?

Tags: javascript, console

I have no clue how to do this, and Google doesn't provide any relevant information.

I would assume that there is no easy way to do this, as a website running code on another website seems like a huge security flaw.

Just to be sure, is there any possible way to do this in JS? Or should I switch to another programming language?

Comment: Read up on how *userscript* browser extensions like TamperMonkey & ViolentMonkey work

Comment: Do you have any sources that I can read up on?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "ON" the opened website. When you open a link, you download the page data and you can do whatever you like to it. What is your end goal? You can go nuts with Puppeteer https://pptr.dev

Comment: Do you mean to change the code of the current website? Or do you want to do something else?

Comment: Lots of information on web regarding how userscripts work as well as docs for various extensions mentioned